# SQL Запрос выполняется в phpmyadmin, но ругается при запуске из php

Tags: php, mysql

Не могу понять в чём дело. есть SQL запрос, он считает разнице времени между последней записью и добавляемой и записывает результат в нужное поле добавляемой записи:

```
SET @variable1 = (SELECT TIMEDIFF (NOW(), (SELECT Date FROM SMARTHOME_BD.HistoryStatusPomp ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)));
INSERT INTO SMARTHOME_BD.HistoryStatusPomp (`StatusPomp`, `Date`, `interval` ) VALUES (0, NOW(), @variable1)
```

Код успешно и правильно выполняется из phpmyadmin (SQL запросом), но ругается, когда я пытаюсь его выполнить в php с помощью **mysqli_query**  с ошибкой:

```
Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO SMARTHOME_BD.HistoryStatusPomp (StatusPomp, Date, interval ) V' at line 2 in C:\OpenServer\domains\SMARTHOME\HOSTS\Pomp\sqlrequest_pomp.php:77
```

Прошу помощи. Эта ошибка (якобы с синтаксисом) сбивает меня с толу и мне неясно куда копать. Спасибо

Comment: не надо кастрировать сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо за указание.

Comment: `mysqli_query` может выполнять только один запрос за один вызов.

Comment: Уберите нафиг промежуточную переменную, используйте INSERT .. SELECT. PS. И вообще - забудьте про INSERT .. VALUES, оно придумано исключительно для вставки статических значений (литералов).

Comment: Ну так я и вставляю конкретные (статические) значения, а не значения из другой таблицы, где (и зачем) мне использовать select? StatusPomp = 0, Date = NOW(). И только interval требует обработки уже имеющихся значений, в той же кстати, таблице

Comment: "И только interval требует обработки уже имеющихся значений, в той же кстати, таблице" Из чего следует что ты вставляешь НЕ статическое значение.

Comment: Верно, но как использовать VALUES и SELECT в одном запросе INSERT?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from

Comment: Я читал эту тему. У меня не работает, так как в select, который в VALUES у меня есть ещё один select, который возвращает разницу времени (TIMEDIFF) между последней записью и текущим временем. Вот он- SELECT (TIMEDIFF (NOW(), (SELECT Date FROM SMARTHOME_BD.HistoryStatusPomp ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1). И mySQL  ругается на синтаксис

Comment: А не работает-то почему? Ошибка выпадает или что?

Comment: Вот такой запрос INSERT INTO SMARTHOME_BD.HistoryStatusPomp (`StatusPomp`, `Date`, `interval` ) VALUES(0,  now(), SELECT (TIMEDIFF (NOW(), (SELECT Date FROM SMARTHOME_BD.HistoryStatusPomp ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)); даёт такую ошибку У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'SELECT (TIMEDIFF (NOW(), (SELECT Date FROM SMARTHOME_BD.HistoryStatusPomp ORDER ' на строке 1

Comment: Ну как минимум я вижу две незакрытые `(`. В итоге - ты либо разбираешься с `insert select`, либо два раза вызываешь `mysqli_query`.

Comment: незакрытые скобки это выдранный из контекста кусок запроса (полный запрос в тексте темы). "ты либо разбираешься с insert select, либо два раза вызываешь mysqli_query" вы могли бы сэкономить нам обоим время не постя подобные пустышки.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO SMARTHOME_BD.HistoryStatusPomp (`StatusPomp`, `Date`, `interval` )
SELECT 0, NOW(),
TIMEDIFF (NOW(), (SELECT `Date` FROM SMARTHOME_BD.HistoryStatusPomp ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1))

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите